# Cómo establecer parámetros de consulta de mysql en un reporte FPDF?

Tags: php, sql, fpdf

Estoy intentando realizar un reporte con la librería `FPDF` de `php`, y tengo problemas a realizar la consulta en `mysql` y mostrarla en el reporte, pues cuando le establezco parámetros de una variable a función `WHERE`, me lanza error la librería. Pero si defino los valores desde el `sql`, si se muestra todo bien.

Pues la finalidad del reporte es que que me muestre solo la fecha colocada en un `input` haciendo un filtrado con la función `WHERE` en `sql`. En error está en la variable `$consultaReporte` que contiene el `sql`.

````
require('fpdf/fpdf.php');  
class PDF extends FPDF  
{
// Cabecera de página  
function Header()  
{
 // Logo  
 //$this->Image('logo_pb.png',10,8,33);  
 // Arial bold 15  
 $this->SetFont('Arial','B',15);  
 // Movernos a la derecha  
 $this->Cell(80);  
 // Título
 $this->Cell(30,10,'Title',1,0,'C');
 // Salto de línea
 $this->Ln(20);
}

// Pie de página
function Footer()
{
 // Posición: a 1,5 cm del final
 $this->SetY(-15);
 // Arial italic 8
 $this->SetFont('Arial','I',8);
 // Número de página
 $this->Cell(0,10,'Pagina'.$this->PageNo().'/{nb}',0,0,'C');
}
}


require 'conexion.php';


$consultaReporte = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM datebaseasistencia WHERE fecha = '$fecha' AND turno = '$turno'");
//$consultaReporteResultado = $mysqli->query($consultaReporte);

$pdf = new PDF();
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);

 $pdf->Cell(35,10,'Fecha',1,0,'C',0);
 $pdf->Cell(35,10,'Ruta',1,0,'C',0);
 $pdf->Cell(35,10,'Turno',1,0,'C',0);
 $pdf->Cell(35,10,'Hora',1,0,'C',0);
 $pdf->Cell(35,10,'Trabajadores',1,1,'C',0);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($consultaReporte)) {

 $pdf->Cell(35,10, $row['fecha'],1,0,'C',0);
 $pdf->Cell(35,10, $row['ruta'],1,0,'C',0);
 $pdf->Cell(35,10, $row['turno'],1,0,'C',0);
 $pdf->Cell(35,10, $row['hora'],1,0,'C',0);
 $pdf->Cell(35,10, $row['trabajadores'],1,1,'C',0);
}

$pdf->Output();
?>`<?php
require('fpdf/fpdf.php');
class PDF extends FPDF
{
// Cabecera de página
function Header()
{
 // Logo
 //$this->Image('logo_pb.png',10,8,33);
 // Arial bold 15
 $this->SetFont('Arial','B',15);
 // Movernos a la derecha
 $this->Cell(80);
 // Título
 $this->Cell(30,10,'Title',1,0,'C');
 // Salto de línea
 $this->Ln(20);
}

// Pie de página
function Footer()
{
 // Posición: a 1,5 cm del final
 $this->SetY(-15);
 // Arial italic 8
 $this->SetFont('Arial','I',8);
 // Número de página
 $this->Cell(0,10,'Pagina'.$this->PageNo().'/{nb}',0,0,'C');
}
}


require 'conexion.php';


> $consultaReporte = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM
> datebaseasistencia WHERE fecha = '$fecha' AND turno = '$turno'");

//$consultaReporteResultado = $mysqli->query($consultaReporte);

$pdf = new PDF();
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);

 $pdf->Cell(35,10,'Fecha',1,0,'C',0);
 $pdf->Cell(35,10,'Ruta',1,0,'C',0);
 $pdf->Cell(35,10,'Turno',1,0,'C',0);
 $pdf->Cell(35,10,'Hora',1,0,'C',0);
 $pdf->Cell(35,10,'Trabajadores',1,1,'C',0);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($consultaReporte)) {

 $pdf->Cell(35,10, $row['fecha'],1,0,'C',0);
 $pdf->Cell(35,10, $row['ruta'],1,0,'C',0);
 $pdf->Cell(35,10, $row['turno'],1,0,'C',0);
 $pdf->Cell(35,10, $row['hora'],1,0,'C',0);
 $pdf->Cell(35,10, $row['trabajadores'],1,1,'C',0);
}

$pdf->Output();    
?>```
````

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error?  ¿Dónde defines las variables `$fecha` y `$turno` que estás usando en la consulta? Puede que esté dando error porque esas variables no existen.

Comment: La variable existe en otra pagina php, en lo cual hago un require para llamarla, $fecha y $turno son dos varibles que se envian por el metodo post desde un formulario. y son la que quiero me que den los parametros donde voy a buscar en mi base de datos amigo.

Comment: Entonces agrega a la pregunta el error que estás recibiendo.

Answer (score 0):

Sería bueno si incluyes el código del PHP en donde envías los parámetros.
Como dices que es con **POST**, deberías capturar esos valores en las variables y luego pasarlos a tu consulta.

```
$fecha = $_POST['fecha'];
$turno = $_POST['turno'];

$consultaReporte = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM datebaseasistencia WHERE fecha = '$fecha' AND turno = '$turno'");
```

Comment: Gracias amigo lo intentare!!

Answer (score 0):

Ya solucione el problema!! Primero: no tenia las varibles declaradas como dijo el compañero eric y coloque la parte para generar el reporte como una nueva pagina y no como una opcion. Coloque que los valores se me llenaran en un formulario y estos fueran mis paramatros. Sin incluir otra pagina php. De verdad gracias por toda yo ayuda.